# Why inserting into unordered_map of pair<T, T> and double always inserts into first item?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, unordered-map

I tried to built graph class which contains of vertoces and edges.
My Vertex class:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Vertex
{
private:
    T data;

public:
    Vertex(const T &data_) : data(data_) {}

public:
    T const& get_data() const { return data; }
};
```

My Graph.h file:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include "Vertex.h"

struct pair_hash
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2>& pair) const {
        return std::hash<T1>()(pair.first) ^ std::hash<T2>()(pair.second);
    }
};

template <typename T>
using EdgeKey = std::pair<Vertex<T>*, Vertex<T>*>;

template <typename T>
using Edges = std::unordered_map<EdgeKey<T>, double, pair_hash>;

template <typename T>
class Graph
{
private:
    std::vector <std::unique_ptr<Vertex<T>>> vertices;
    Edges<T> edges;

public:
    Graph(std::vector <std::unique_ptr<Vertex<T>>>&& vertices_, Edges<T> && edges_)
        : vertices(std::move(vertices_)), edges(std::move(edges_)) {}

};
}
```

in my main.cpp file I managed to create new vertices and pass them to constructor of a Graph class:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Vertex<int>> v1(new Vertex<int>(1));
    std::unique_ptr<Vertex<int>> v2(new Vertex<int>(2));
    std::unique_ptr<Vertex<int>> v3(new Vertex<int>(3));
    std::unique_ptr<Vertex<int>> v4(new Vertex<int>(4));
    std::unique_ptr<Vertex<int>> v5(new Vertex<int>(5));

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Vertex<int>>> vertices_;
    vertices_.push_back(std::move(v1));
    vertices_.push_back(std::move(v2));
    vertices_.push_back(std::move(v3));
    vertices_.push_back(std::move(v4));
    vertices_.push_back(std::move(v5));


    Edges<int> edges_;
        
    EdgeKey<int> p12(v1.get(), v2.get());
    double w1 = 7.5;

    EdgeKey<int> p13(v1.get(), v2.get());
    double w2 = 2.5;

    EdgeKey<int> p45(v4.get(), v5.get());
    double w3 = 4.5;

    edges_[p12] = w1;
    edges_[p13] = w2;
    edges_[p45] = w3;

    Graph<int> G1(std::move(vertices_), std::move(edges_));

    return 0;
}
```

But then I try to print some data about my edges, I get weird results:
in main.cpp:

```cpp
    std::cout << vertices_.size() << std::endl;

    std::cout << &p12 << " " << &p13 << " "<< &p45 << std::endl;

    std::cout << edges_[p12] << std::endl;
    std::cout << edges_[p13] << std::endl;
    std::cout << edges_[p45] << std::endl;

    std::cout << edges_.size() << std::endl;

    for (auto& x : edges_) {
        std::cout << ": " << x.second << std::endl;
    }
```

```
5
00000008C793F028 00000008C793F078 00000008C793F0C8
4.5 
4.5
4.5
1
:4.5
```

It seems like all new edges added to unordered map replace previously added. Am I missing something?

Comment: You moved `v1` to `v5` into `vertices_`, so when you do `v1.get()` afterwards, it is going to be a null pointer.

Comment: Print `p12.first`, `p12.second`, ... instead of `&p12`, ... The locations of `p12` and the others are irrelevant.

Comment: Then change to `EdgeKey<int> p12(vertices_[0].get(), vertices_[1].get());` and compare the results.

Comment: And do spend some time thinking about what transferring ownership of a uniquely-owned object to a new owner does to its original owner.